# How to collect EMail data from HTML forms?

Tags: html, forms, email

I've been setting up my website. I wanna run it on Wordpress. Have already purchased the domain name, and have a small hosting.

For now, my goal is to create the "COMING SOON" index.html. I did, however faced a lil problem, which I can't solve.

I have a form there, which is to notify people when my site launches. They simply put their emails in the form, and I have to find them after.

Here is the code:

```
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <h1>Nakashidze.com</h1>
                <p id="o">My website is</p>
                <h2>Coming Soon</h2>
                <p>But you can find me here:</p>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/musemadridista"><img src="images/fb.png" /></a><a href="http://www.twitter.com/miknakk"><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a><a href="http://linkedin.com/in/mikheilnak"><img src="images/linkedin.png" /></a>
                <p>Wanna know when it's ready? Sign up!</p>
                <form method="POST" action="doc.php">
                <div id="sub">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your@email.com" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'your@email.com'" /> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I've tried to look for the answer in here, as long as there are quite a few similar questions, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of HTML or PHP?

Comment: Do you want their emails sent to you by email or stored on the server?

Comment: So you have a page styled with some CSS with a Facebook link and a form. This form collects an email address, and upon submission, hands it over to doc.php - the problem you're having is what doc.php needs to do to give you that information. You can insert the email into a table of a database that you will refer to when you need a list or you can go as far as to email yourself that "email X has subscribed" and keep count yourself. The best option, if you have no programming experience and are using WordPress, is what gat mentioned: utilizing a plugin or third-party service to keep records.

Comment: [Here is a tutorial on php forms](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html)

Comment: Allowing a bad guy to sign up a victim's address is an attractive nuisance. If it's just one message, it's a fairly minor nuisance; but really, don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with services like http://launchrock.co/ or Wordpress plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/. You need no programming experience to use either of these options.

Otherwise if you prefer to build your own page, you'd need some working knowledge of a server side programming language.